# clearcase query on moving files to a new folder in the same VOB

Tags: clearcase

we have a branch created , config spec of which looks like this

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../project_name/LATEST
element * some_label -mkbranch project_name
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch project_name
```

now there is a folder which looks like this

```
abc\bcd\efg which has certain .xls files, need to move these files to a new folder under efg
i.e abc\bcd\efg\hij\
```

how do I go about this?

Can someone help? Im very new to clearcase, it would be great if you can tell me any services need to be stopped or any tags need to be untagged or stuff like that

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move them through the GUI, but in command line, you need to checkout the source folder and the destination folder.

See more at "[To move an element within a VOB](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_move_withinvob.htm)"

1. Check out the parent directory and the destination directory.
2. Enter the following command:

   ```
   cleartool mv element-name destination-directory
   ```
3. Check in the new parent directory and the source directory.

> This operation changes the location (and optionally, the name) of an element or VOB symbolic link.
>   For a file element that is checked out to your view, it relocates the checked-out version also. (That is, it moves the view-private file with the same name as the element.)
>   If the version is checked out to another view, you receive a warning message that you have view-private data that may need to be moved.